# Special Characters in Subject Line Converting to ASCII

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We use HTTPGET to pull our subject lines for daily newsletters, it pull the latest article title. For some reason, if the title has an & or é, Marketing Cloud will convert those characters to ASCII. If I type them in myself, in the subject field, it fine.

I've tried not encoding and encoding the title as UTF-8, but it made no difference. Am I missing something?

Here the subject line code:

```
 %%=HTTPGet("http://www.site.com/newsletters/subject_daily.php")=%%
```

Loop to get subject:
     require( 'settings_glossy.php' );

```
 foreach( $subject as $s ) {
     foreach( $articles_array as $article ) {
     if( $s['id'] == $article['id'] ) {
       echo cleaner( $article[ 'title' ][ 'rendered' ] );
     }
       break;
   }
 }
```

Cleaner function:

```
  function cleaner($dirty, $strip = true){
        if($strip === true) {
              $dirty = strip_tags($dirty);
        }
        $output = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $dirty);
        return $output;
  }
```

Comment: Try using %%=TreatAsContent(HTTPGET("etc.."))=%%.  This may help to render the content correctly.

Comment: Stick your url in Fiddler or something to make sure it reports that the encoding is in UTF8. From memory httpget obeys the encoding of the page requested, however content areas might ignore it all

Comment: Is there a better method to achieve this? In the end, this is pulling form a JSON feed.

Comment: I spoke with support over the phone and they mentioned it was a known bug. Can anyone confirm that?